# How to calculate number of IP's from 2 IP addresses more efficiently?

Tags: c#, ip, range, ping

I am working on pinging app in which I have a progress bar which displays progress of pinging of range IPs.

This is how I calculate the range of IPs to set as maximum value for the progress bar:

```
pbProgress.Maximum = 1 + (IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder
    (BitConverter.ToInt32(IPAddress.Parse(txtTo.Text).GetAddressBytes(), 0)) -
    IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32
    (IPAddress.Parse(txtFrom.Text).GetAddressBytes(), 0)));
```

The problem here is that I put range starting from 0.0.0.0 to 1.0.0.0 it takes an awful amount of time to calculate the range, therefore passing the value to the progress bar maximum value. Is there any better solution to calculate the number of IPs quicker?

I could always put a limit of IP addresses to ping for example to 10k addresses, but I just don't want to limit any functionality of this program.

Any ideas?

Comment: Convert them to int, and calculate the difference. There are plenty of duplicates.

Comment: Still working on that project? :D

Comment: @BlackBear, I took a bit off, just trying to perfect it :) I noticed that if range is too large my program get stuck for like 10 minutes so I want to fix that.

Comment: How much is an "awful amount of time"? On my computer it takes under 1ms.

Comment: @Gabe: I think he's talking about the total running time ip addresses pinging time included

Comment: @Gabe, oh wait, You might be right, it happens when I use threads.. When threading is not set then it works fast...

Comment: @BlackBear, no. Just calculating the range though. I think there's something wrong with the threading. It's good when someone else try the code and point things out a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're creating some data structure, like a list or array, containing each of the IP addresses. All you need to do is iterate over them with something like a `for` loop so they are generated as needed rather than before you start.

Since you want to use multiple threads, try using something like [`Parallel.For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781401.aspx).

Comment: Ah, so you are saying that basically I'm creating a large amount of data and placing it to the memory? Well this is weird and I think that you might have some good points here. Although I don't understand why it works fast with out threads. I must double check that. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I found the cause of my problem. It's not the calculation (as I originally thought) but I had a for loop which loaded every ping on other thread making app memory hog.